# Python - Big(O) Runtime: List Comprehension & For Loop

Tags: python, for-loop, big-o, list-comprehension

In CTCI(Python version), the runtime of the code below is described to be O(N)

```
# O(N)

def unique(string):
    # Assuming character set is ASCII (128 characters)
    if len(string) > 128:
        return False

    char_set = [False for _ in range(128)]
    for char in string:
        val = ord(char)
        if char_set[val]:
            # Char already found in string
            return False
        char_set[val] = True

    return True
```

This really confuses me as I see a list comprehension in the formation of `char_set` and another for loop right after... shouldn't the run-time be O(N ^ 2)?

Edit: I'm also confused as to why Laakman uses len(string) > 128 to check for ascii char. Wouldn't that just give the length of the string in question and not the character value which the `ord` method in Python gives?

Edit1: Can the same be achieved if she doesn't use `val = ord(char)` ? That would change the next line to `if char_set[char]:`

Comment: Key phrase: "*another for loop right **after***". The two for-loops are separate, not nested.

Comment: And even if they were nested, the first for loop is a constant size of 128, it is not dependent on the size of the input.

Comment: FWIW you don't even have to have a loop: `char_set = [False] * 128`

Answer (score 1):

The amount of time `[False for _ in range(128)]` takes is fixed and therefore has a time complexity of `O(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, the point is that this code is intended to check that every character in the string is unique. Assuming that the string is ASCII, if it is longer than 128 characters it cannot possibly contain only unique characters since there are only 128 characters in the ASCII charset to begin with.

Comment: ah i never thought about it that way! that cleared up a LOT! so its not necessary to use `ord` to check whether each char in the string is ASCII?